# Applying a function element-wise to multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have two numpy arrays of the same dimensions, e.g.:

```
a = np.ones((4,))
b = np.linspace(0,4,4)
```

and a function that is supposed to operate on **elements** of those arrays:

```
def my_func (x,y):
   # do something, e.g.
   z = x+y
   return z
```

How can I apply this function to the elements of `a` and `b` in an element-wise fashion and get the result back?

Comment: You need to provide more data about your function. As is the answer is trivially `a+b`.

Comment: Or trivially `my_func(a,b)`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, really. For the given function; how about 'a+b', for instance? Presumably you have something more complex in mind though.

The most general solution is np.vectorize; but its also the slowest. Depending on what you want to do, more clever solutions may exist though. Take a look at numexp for example.